# starting and stopping tomcat using ANT script?

Tags: java, tomcat, ant

I have below ANT script to start/stop tomcat:

```
   <project name="sample">
<property name="name" value="sample"/>
<path id="catalina-ant-classpath"> 
<fileset dir="D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\lib"> 
<include name="catalina-ant.jar"/> 
</fileset> 
</path> 
<taskdef name="start" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StartTask"> 
<classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/> 
</taskdef>

<taskdef name="stop" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StopTask">
<classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>

<target name="start" description="Start Tomcat application">
<start url="http://localhost:8080/manager"
username="uname"
password="pwd"/>
</target>
<target name="stop" description="Stop Tomcat application">
<stop url="http://localhost:8080/manager"
username="uname"
password="pwd"/>
</target>
</project>
```

When i run above script it throws below Error:

**D:\apache-ant-1.9.3-bin\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin>ant build.xml stop
Buildfile: D:\apache-ant-1.9.3-bin\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin\build.xml
BUILD FAILED
Target "build.xml" does not exist in the project "sample".**

Is there any wrong in above script?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this your full build.xml ?

Comment: yes Sanjeev...this is my build.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your build.xml is missing the root element `<project>`. Please see ant documentation.

Remove the `name` attribute it is optional.

Comment: Sanjeev, now i am getting below error: D:\apache-ant-1.9.3-bin\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin\build.xml:3: taskdef class org.apac
he.catalina.ant.StartTask cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[]

Comment: this usually happens because of class path. check your class path and make sure `catalina-ant.jar` is added correctly.

Comment: Sanjeev, i have a doubt. I have not created any project. I just created above build.xml. Now i should start/stop tomcat with above script. Is it possible?

Comment: Just use any name for your project because this is mandatory root element to define ant project and try `    <path id="catalina-ant-classpath">
        
        <fileset dir="D:/apache-tomcat-7.0.47-windows-x64/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/server/lib">
            <include name="catalina-ant.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <taskdef name="start" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StartTask">
        <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
    </taskdef>`

Comment: Sanjeev now am getting: BUILD FAILED
D:\apache-ant-1.9.3-bin\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin\build.xml:8: D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.4
7-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\server\lib does not exist.

Comment: so here is your error .. use the correct path to catalina-ant.jar

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47402/discussion-between-sanjeev-and-user755806)